# msg's executing time is too long in Android Java

Tags: java, android, mobile

I know this is common to ask but I have trouble using `super.onBackPressed();` that it crash my app eventually, So let's say I'm in the **second activity** and I want to go back to the mainActivity.The problem is when I go back the logcat says `msg's executing time is too long` and sometimes it crashes the app, can someone have an idea for this?

**second activity** goes back to second activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**first activity** goes to 2nd activity : I didn't `finish()` the intent because I use `backPressed` on second activity

```
    InventoryList.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.example.cashgrantsmobile.Inventory.InventoryList.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
```